# How to set a cut off value for blob_doh in scikit-image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to detect circular features in a DTM (rendered to 8 bit and values ranging from 0-255) using blob_doh in python. I want to set a cut-off value so that the method does not look for circles for values `> 230`. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can zero out the unnecessary pixels

```
img[img>230] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, Vighnesh.Now it does the piece of work I wanted to do. Basically, I am using the typical code for blob extraction (blob_doh), and I am looking for a way to export the coordinates of the circles that blob_doh draws around the blobs in a suitable form so that I can import each circle in ArcGIS as separate feature, in order to create polygons and so forth.

Comment: You can use the [circle_perimeter](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#circle-perimeter) function to get the coordinates

Comment: Alternatively, can someone define the domain of blob_doh e.g. [0-200] instead of zeroing out pixels? If yes what are the necessary lines to be added to the code? Thanks